# Partial mock of class that takes HttpClient as argument

Tags: c#, .net, integration-testing, moq

In a ASP.NET Core integration test I want to test some code that involves a service `IMyService`:

```
Task<string> GetAsync(int id);

Task DeleteAsync(int id);
```

An implementation takes a `HttpClient` as argument:

```
public MyService(HttpClient client)
{
    _client = client ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(client));
}

public async Task<string> GetAsync(int id) { }

public virtual async Task DeleteAsync(int id) { }
```

It is registered with AddHttpClient in `Program.cs` (with .NET 6, but in `Startup.cs` with .NET 5):

```
services.AddHttpClient("MyService");
```

I want to keep the `GetAsync` real implementation and mock only the `DeleteAsync` method:

```
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TProgram>
    : WebApplicationFactory<TProgram> where TProgram : class
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder
            .ConfigureTestServices(services =>
            {
                var myServiceMock = new Mock<MyService>
                {
                    CallBase = true,
                };

                myServiceMock.Setup(x =>
                        x.DeleteAsync(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(Task.CompletedTask);

                // register the mock, how?
            });
    }
}
```

How can I register my mock? Since the class has a constructor with a parameter, I need to pass that parameter, or the instantiation will fail:

> Can not instantiate proxy of class. Could not find a parameterless constructor.

I cannot understand how I am going to be able to access `myServiceMock.Object` without Moq failing, because I want the real `HttpClient` to be used.

So, how can I register my mock?

Comment: I am confused, if you are after an integration test, why are you mocking anything?

Comment: That's a good question. I just want to exclude one particular method, but maybe that's wrong approach. Maybe I shouldn't do that. Maybe I should really test the `Delete` method as well.

Comment: In case of integration test you should NOT mock your code. You might need to mock your external dependencies (like 1st and 3rd party services). In case of Http calls you can create mock http server via [WireMock.Net](https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net) or [Stubbery](https://github.com/markvincze/Stubbery).